# Showing $\frac{\pi}{4}= 2 \arctan\frac13+\arctan\frac17$ by using multiplication of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, triangles

Imagine three right triangles on top of each other. The legs of the first two triangles have the ratio $1/3$ and the third triangle $1/7$. The total angle of all three angles is $\pi/4$.

I can get that with the arctan, of course, but I don't know how to use the complex numbers. Because the task is:

> Show that
> $$\frac{\pi}{4}= 2 \arctan\frac13+\arctan\frac17$$
> by using multiplication of complex numbers.

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. You can learn how to do better math formatting (try to search "mathjax"). Also, try to improve the overall formatting please, so it is more pleasant to read.

Answer (score 3):

We have the following expansion :

$$(1+\tfrac13i)^{\color{red}{2}}(1+\tfrac17i)=\frac{50}{63}(1+i)\tag{1}$$

[image]

from which we retrieve at once the following relationship on the arguments (remember : argument of a product of complex numbers = sum of their arguments mod. $2 \pi$):

$$ \color{red}{2} \operatorname{atan} \tfrac13 + \operatorname{atan} \tfrac17 = \underbrace{\operatorname{atan} 1}_{\pi/4} + 2k \pi$$

for a certain integer $k$ which is necessarily $0$.

Remark: (1) can be seen as successive similitudes applied to the hypotenuses of the right triangles:

$$(1+\tfrac13i)\xrightarrow{\times (1+\tfrac13i)}(\tfrac89+\tfrac23i)\xrightarrow{\times (1+\tfrac17i)}\frac{50}{63}(1+i)$$

Answer (score 2):

This question is equivalent to finding the product

$$(3+i) \cdot (3+i) \cdot (7+i)$$

and expecting it in the form $n(1+i)$.

Do you see why?

This is because $\arg(3+i) = \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{3}$, $\arg(7+i) = \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{7}$ and $\arg \lambda(1+i)=\frac{\pi}{4}$. On complex multiplication, principal arguments add up. So it can be concluded that

$$2\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{3}+\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{7}=n\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$$

As noted by @MarkSaving, complex multiplication in general helps only upto multiples of $\pi$. We need to take into account $0 < \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{7} < \frac{\pi}{4}$ and  $0 < \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{3} < \frac{\pi}{4}$ so that the sum

$$0 < 2\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{3}+\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{7}<\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

from where it can be seen that our sum can be equal to $\pi/4$ only.

Comment: Actually, this is not enough, because it only determines the sum up to a multiple of $\pi$. A small amount of inequality analysis is required.

Comment: @MarkSaving Well-spotted. We also need $0\le\arctan\tfrac13\le\tfrac{\pi}{4}$ etc. to prove $0\le2\arctan\tfrac13+\arctan\tfrac17<\tfrac{3\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much @MarkSaving and J.G. Edited to cover this argument.

Answer (score 1):

When we convert $z=x+yi\ne0$ to $z=re^{it}$, polar form, then it satisfies these two equation $x=r\cos t, y=r\sin t$, so $\frac yx=\tan t$.

Then, $t=\tan^{-1}\frac yx$.

So...

$$50\sqrt2e^{\frac{i\pi}4}=50(1+i)=(3+i)^2(7+i)=(r_1e^{i\tan^{-1}\frac13})^2(r_2e^{i\tan^{-1}\frac1t})=r_1r_2e^{i(2\tan^{-1}\frac13+\tan^{-1}\frac17)}$$

Then following is true:
$$\frac{\pi}{4}= 2 \arctan\frac13+\arctan\frac17$$

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$
\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =\tan^{-1}[\tan(\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y )]
$$
i.e.
$$
\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)
$$

we have

$$
2\tan \frac{1}{3}=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{1- \frac{1}{9}}\right)=\tan^{-1}\frac{6}{8}=\tan^{-1}\frac{3}{4}
$$
and
$$
2\tan \frac{1}{3}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{7}=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{7}}{1- \frac{3}{28}}\right)=\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac{25}{28}}{\frac{25}{28}}=\tan^{-1}(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If all we were familiar with was the basic Euler form, $ \ e^{ \ i·\theta} \ = \ \cos \theta + i·\sin \theta \ \ , \ $ and the fact that multiplication of two (unit-modulus) complex numbers adds the angles (arguments) of those numbers $ [ \ (\cos \alpha + i·\sin \alpha)·(\cos \beta + i·\sin \beta) \ = \   \cos (\alpha + \beta) + i·\sin (\alpha + \beta)  \ ] \ \  , \ $ that and the "angle-addition" and "double-angle" formulas for sine and cosine would be enough to accomplish the demonstration.  (This puts the argument reasonably within reach of a student near the end of their pre-calculus course.)

We may designate two angles subject to the conditions $ \ \tan \phi \ = \ \frac13 \ \Rightarrow \ \sin \phi \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \ \ , \ \ \cos \phi \ = \ \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} \ \ $ and $ \ \tan \psi \ = \ \frac17 \ \Rightarrow \ \sin \psi \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{50}} \ \ , \ \ \cos \psi \ = \ \frac{7}{\sqrt{50}} \ \ . \ $  These angles will be added in the fashion specified in the problem by forming the complex product $$ \ (\cos \phi + i·\sin \phi)·(\cos \phi + i·\sin \phi)·(\cos \psi + i·\sin \psi) \ = \ \cos (2 \phi + \psi) \ + \ i·\sin (2 \phi + \psi) \ \ . $$

The "angle-addition" formulas then produce

$$ \cos (2 \phi + \psi) \ + \ i·\sin (2 \phi + \psi) $$ $$ = \ \ [ \ \cos (2 \phi)·\cos \psi \ - \ \ \sin (2 \phi)·\sin \psi \ ] \ \ + \ \ i \ · \ [ \ \sin (2 \phi)·\cos \psi \ + \ \ \cos (2 \phi)·\sin \psi \ ] \ \ . $$

We could then either insert the expressions of the "double-angle" formulas for cosine and sine into this result, or use it to calculate the trigonometric function values of $ \ 2·\phi \ $ first:

$$ \sin (2 \phi) \ \ = \ \ 2·\sin \phi·\cos \phi \ \ = \ \ 2·\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}·\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}  \ \ = \ \ \frac{6}{10} \ \ = \ \ \frac35 \ \ , \ \ $$
$$ \cos (2 \phi) \ \ = \ \ \cos^2 \phi \ - \ \sin^2 \phi \ \ = \ \ \frac{9}{ 10} \ - \ \frac{1}{10} \ \ = \ \ \frac{8}{10} \ \ = \ \ \frac45 \ \ , \ \ $$
$$ \text{or} \ \ \ \sqrt{1 \ - \ \sin^2 (2 \phi)} \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{1 \ - \ \left(\frac35 \right)^2 } \ \ = \ \ \frac45 \ \ . $$

The product of our three complex numbers is thus
$$ \cos (2 \phi + \psi) \ + \ i·\sin (2 \phi + \psi) $$ $$ = \ \ \left[ \ \frac45·\frac{7}{\sqrt{50}} \ - \ \ \frac35·\frac{1}{\sqrt{50}} \ \right] \ \ + \ \ i · \left[ \ \frac35·\frac{7}{\sqrt{50}} \ + \ \ \frac45·\frac{1}{\sqrt{50}} \ \right]  $$
$$ = \ \ \left[ \  \frac{28 \ - \ 3}{5 \ · \ 5\sqrt2} \  \right] \  + \  i · \left[ \ \frac{21 \ + \ 4}{5 \ · \ 5\sqrt2} \  \right] \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt2}  \  + \  i ·  \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ \ = \ \ \cos \frac{\pi}{4} \ + \ i·\sin \frac{\pi}{4} \ \ . $$

The "argument-addition" which occurs in the complex multiplication therefore shows that $ \ 2 · \arctan \frac13 \  + \  \arctan \frac17 \ \ = \ \ \frac{\pi}{4} \ \ . \ $  (The more sophisticated methods shown in other answers are, to be sure, more concise.)